# Neo4j Cypher query Optional match with multiple CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The scenario is to get the sum of values of the nodes matched using multiple optional matches and then the value is selected based on the matching case

```
MATCH (a:Type1 {id: '1234'})-[:REL_W]->(parentNode:Type2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parentNode)<-[:REL_P]-(:Type2:Type3)-[:REL_W]->(qnode:Type1)
WITH qnode AS qwt
OPTIONAL MATCH (parentNode)<-[:REL_P]-(:Type2:Type4)-[:REL_I]-(:Type2)<-[:REL_W]-(lnode:Type1)
WITH qwt, lnode AS lwt
WITH qwt, lwt,
     CASE
         WHEN qwt IS NOT NULL AND 'Static' IN labels(qwt)
         THEN toFloat(qwt.value)
         WHEN lwt IS NOT NULL AND 'Static' IN labels(lwt)
         THEN toFloat(lwt.value)
         ELSE 0
     END AS childWeight
RETURN sum(childWeight) AS weight;
```

The problem with this code is always the second CASE is not executed. The optional match is retuning qwt and lwt nodes and then data is also correct. If we make the 'lwt' case the first one then it is executing but 'qwt' case will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. Here are some major ones:

1. Your first `WITH` does not specify `parentNode`, so the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` has to find all possible matching nodes instead of re-using the `parentNode` found earlier. This is obviously bad for your results and slows down the query.
2. Each `MATCH` clause (whether `OPTIONAL` or not) will cause a multiplication in the number of working rows unless you do something to prevent that (like doing an aggregation in between `MATCH` clauses). For example, if you already have 5 rows and a `MATCH` generates 10 results, then you end up with 50 rows. This will obviously greatly skew the eventual sum.

Here is a query that should work better (and it also addresses some other inefficiencies):

```
MATCH (:Type1 {id: '1234'})-[:REL_W]->(:Type2)<-[:REL_P]-(t2:Type2)
CALL {
  WITH t2
  MATCH (t2:Type3)-[:REL_W]->(qnode:Type1:Static)
  RETURN SUM(TOFLOAT(qnode.value)) AS qSum
}
CALL {
  WITH t2
  MATCH (t2:Type4)-[:REL_I]-(:Type2)<-[:REL_W]-(lnode:Type1:Static)
  RETURN SUM(TOFLOAT(lnode.value)) AS lSum
}
RETURN qSum + lSum AS weight
```

Also, you should should consider changing the stored `value` properties to floating point (instead of what I assume are strings). That will allow you to remove the `TOFLOAT`s and speed up your query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the above query fails when either of the blocks doesn’t have matching nodes.

Comment: It fails in what way? And what neo4j version are you using?

Comment: For example if there are no matching nodes of type qnode:Type1:static but there are matching nodes of lnode:type1:static the expectation is lsum has to be returned but the output is no matching nodes. Version is neo4j community 4.4.4

Comment: Version 4.4.4 is very old. The latest version is 5.11, and there have been many changes and improvements. If possible, your should update to 5.11. My answer should work in any 5.x version. Let me know if that is not possible, and I can update my answer to show something that works in 4.4.4 - but that would not be useful to the general neo4j population.